# How to manipulate datagridview columns when using DataSource?

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview, datasource

I am using datagridview on c# and im feeding it with a datasource object. If `AutoGenerateColumns` is `true`, everything works fine and all the columns gets generated with their content. But I want to display only the 1st column, and use the info on the rest of the columns for the 1st column tooltip.

I tried setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` and created a column called like the 1st column added when `AutoGenerateColumns` is `true`, but no rows are being added when I do this.

Whats the right way to do it?

**Update:**
Adding `[Browsable(false)]` above all the fields i want to hide worked :)

Now, how could I use data from the "hidden" columns and use them for the 1st column cells tooltips?

Comment: A code sample is really required to answer this question correctly -- are you sure you hooked up your column correctly? You need to set DataPropertyName on the column to the property you want the column to use

Comment: Are you using visual studio 08/10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in the cell formatting event.  Here is a code snippet from msdn.

```
// Sets the ToolTip text for cells in the Rating column.
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
    if ( (e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["Rating"].Index)
        && e.Value != null )
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = 
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        if (e.Value.Equals("*"))
        {                
            cell.ToolTipText = "very bad"; // you can get the value from your other cells using the above technique with .value instead of .index
        }
        else if (e.Value.Equals("**"))
        {
            cell.ToolTipText = "bad";
        }
        else if (e.Value.Equals("***"))
        {
            cell.ToolTipText = "good";
        }
        else if (e.Value.Equals("****"))
        {
            cell.ToolTipText = "very good";
        }
    }
}
```

[More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.tooltiptext.aspx#Y337)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridStatus" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceForStatusGrid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" Visible =false />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="StudentName" />
```

This way you will have the column in there and you can retrive it use Grid.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[index] .....